# Why $(parent).children(class) doesn't return element?

Tags: jquery, dom

```
var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().attr("id");

alert ($("#"+parent).children(".select_tarif").get());
```

I try to retrieve elements, with parent and class (I can't use only the class, because I have other elements with same class, but variant parent).

The way to retrieve the parent is ugly, but I can't do otherwise (html is generated) and it return what I want.

My problem is, function alert() returns nothing, but it will display element is a select input

Comment: What are you doing with the `.get()` function?

Comment: I use `.get()` to check if I get the element which I want

Comment: Ok :p I thought maybe you were trying to use it to get the contents of the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$("#"+parent).find(".select_tarif")
```

Comment: Thanks, It works, but someone can explain me why the first method doesn't work ? Is it because there are other elements in DOM between "parent" and ".select_tarif" ?

Comment: They have to be direct children. Without seeing your HTML it's hard to say.

Comment: @ Diodeus : Thanks, I only wanted to know why it doesn't work. Function `.find()` is what I searched.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use another selector (and find is better)

```
var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next();

alert (parent.find(".select_tarif").get());
```